# Filter a legend Item with Chartjs.org V2.7

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am building a series of doughnut charts and I would like to remove the second item in the legend, so when I generate the legend with the generateLegend() method I just want to get the first value.

In the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) there is an option that reads

> Filters legend items out of the legend. Receives 2 parameters, a Legend Item and the chart data

But I can't find an example how to use it. In this [Pen](https://codepen.io/ryansegus/pen/VMKqdN) you can see the 2 labels in the middle, I just want to show the first label. I tried different approaches with no success. Just deleting the item doesn't work for me because the `<li>` item still there. Here's the code I am using.

```
$id = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var langDataEs = {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [75, 25],
        backgroundColor: ["#8dc63f", "#1d1d1d"]
      }
    ],
    labels: ["es", "learning"]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      /* I would like to remove the item "learning" */
      filter: function() {

      },
    },
    responsive: true
  }
};

langChartEs = new Chart($id("langEs").getContext("2d"), langDataEs);
$id("es").innerHTML = langChartEs.generateLegend();
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: OMG, I was so focused on doing it vía JavaScript that I never thought about CSS, I'll just hide the second child for now, I won't accept your answer just yet to see if someone  can came up with a JavaScript solution just to learn, thanks so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The filter function works exactly like the Javascript's native `Array.prototype.filter`. So just return true if you want to show the legend at a particular index.

**EDIT:** The filter function would come inside the `labels` field.

```
 legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
           filter: function(legendItem, data) {
                return legendItem.index != 1 
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I tried [here](https://codepen.io/ryansegus/pen/VMKqdN) as you sugested but it doesn't seems to work for me or I am doing it wrong...

Comment: Sorry...my bad. Check my edited version! Hope it works.

Comment: Also it's `legendItem.index` instead of `legendItem.datasetIndex`

Comment: because the filter function is called for each series of data